# Recursive Method to capitalize all characters and add a space between each in Java

Tags: java, string, recursion, replace, character

I am practicing recursive methods, and one of the three I am working on attempts to capitalize an entire string and add a space between each character. Below is my code:

```
public static String toUpper(String str) {

    char ch;

    if(str.length() == 0) {
        return "";
    }

    ch = str.charAt(0); 

    if(Character.isLowerCase(ch)){
        return Character.toUpperCase(ch) + toUpper(str.substring(1));
    }

    String newString = ch + toUpper(str.substring(1));

    /*
     * This is where my issue is.
     * I assumed using the replace method would work just as it does on any other string;
     * however I am getting incorrect output every time.
     */

    return newString.replace("", " ");

}
```

However, it is replacing with more than just a single space, except for between the first two characters, and I cannot figure out why for the life of me. I have tested this use of replace in another non-recursive method, and it works just as I expect it. If you can help me understand this it would be greatly appreciated.

My output looks like this:

```
 H I       T   H   E   R   E       !
```

And I want this:

```
H I   T H E R E !
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be replacing characters, instead first test that you have at least one character (otherwise return the empty string); if you have at least one character, capitalize the first character and then concatenate it with the result of recursively calling your method. Like,

```
public static String toUpper(String str) {
    if (str.length() < 1) {
        return "";
    }
    return Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(0)) + toUpper(str.substring(1));
}
```

to add a space between each character

```
return Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(0)) 
        + " " + toUpper(str.substring(1));
```

Comment: Such a simple solution to what I wanted to do. No idea why I didn't think about just concatenating a space in between. I still don't see why the call on replace doesn't work though, because it does in fact work perfectly for adding spaces how I want on a non-recursive method that does the exact same thing as this recursive method. Nonetheless, thank you so very much! You wouldn't believe how much time I spent trying to figure this out.

Comment: At each step of recursion you add a space between the characters, including the spaces you added in the previous recursive step.